# Why is linking to opengl32.dll required?

Tags: c++, winapi, opengl, glew, glad

In order to use modern OpenGL functions above legacy version 1.1, a loading library is required (unless you manually load the function pointers from the GPU drivers yourself of course). If `opengl32.dll` only contains a software legacy OpenGL 1.1 implementation for windows, why is it still required to be linked to by loading libraries like GLEW or internally loaded by GLAD?

Comment: Where else are you going to get [`wglGetProcAddress()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-wglgetprocaddress) from if not `opengl32.dll`?

Comment: You link to a library for one single reason, always the same:  That's where the code you are calling resides.

Comment: Why do you think that `opengl32.dll` is the legacy OpenGL 1.1?

Comment: Why is this a concern? Windows executables always link to some dlls that are there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As alluded to in the comments above, openGL32.dll contains the method wglGetProcAddress. This is pretty much the only function that you need for openGL.

The loader libraries *(e.g. glew, glad, et al)* are basically a load of function pointers. Those function pointers need to be initialised at startup, hence needing to call glewInit, which will actually just make a load of calls to wglGetProcAddress.

Basically glew will essentially boil down to something along these lines internally:

```cpp
// declare a function pointer type
typedef void (*glFlushPointer)();

// a global function pointer
glFlushPointer glFlush = 0;

#include <GL/gl.h> //< required for wglGetProcAddress

void glewInit() {
    // now repeat this process for every GL function you need...
    glFlush = (glFlushPointer)wglGetProcAddress("glFlush");
}
```

Comment: Well, technically `wglGetProcAddress` is not required return lookups for functions that are already exposed by `opengl32.dll`. Hence loader libraries will usually dispatch to either `kernel32.dll: GetProcAddress` or `opengl32.dll: wglGetProcAddress` depending on if the function in question is already part of OpenGL-1.1 (or how GLAD does it, first attempt `GetProcAddress` and if that fails `wglGetProcAddress`).